# Doctrine swap out table at runtime

Tags: doctrine-orm

Typically when you implement a entity using Doctrine you map it to a table explicitly:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="message")
 */
class Message
{
    //...
}
```

Or you reply on doctrine to implicitly map your class name to a table...I have several tables which are identical in schema but I do not wish to re-create the class for each time...there fore at runtime (dynamically) I would like to change the table name accordingly.

Where do I start or what would I look into overriding to implement this odd requirement???

Comment: Have you read about [mapped superclasses](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses)? To me, your situation sounds like a perfect fit for mapped superclasses.

Comment: I will have to take a look...I have read the docs cover to cover over the last few months I am sure but cannot recall this feature. Thank you :)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not believe this is the solution I was after. Tables in question are created automatically by a business intelligence server. Identical in schema but the data is wildly different. Basically I need one "entity" class which can map to alternately named tables, foriegn keys, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly (to me), the solution is very simple. All you have to do is to get the [`ClassMetadata`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadata.html) of your entity and change the name of the table it maps to:

```
/** @var EntityManager $em */
$class = $em->getClassMetadata('Message');
$class->setPrimaryTable(['name' => 'message_23']);
```

You need to be careful and do not change the table name after you have loaded some entities of type `Message` and changed them. It's a big chance it will either produce SQL errors on saving (because of table constraints, for example), if you are lucky or it will modify the wrong row (from the new table).

I suggest the following workflow:

1. set the desired table name;
2. load some entities;
3. modify them at will;
4. save them;
5. detach them from the entity manager (the method [EntityManager::clear()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#_clear) is a quick way to start over);
6. go back to step 1 (i.e. repeat using another table).

The step #5 (detach the entities from the entity manager) is useful even if you don't change or don't save the entities. It allows the entity manager use less memory and work faster.

This is just one of the many methods you can use to dynamically set/change the mapping. Take a look at the [documentation of class ClassMetadata](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadata.html) for the rest of them. You can find more inspiration in the documentation page of the [PHP mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/php-mapping.html).

Comment: Awesome thanks for that...I shall look into using the approach you recommend :)